# Sending attachments with PHPmailer - returns .dat file

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hopefully someone out there can point out what I've missed!

I have a script which I took from [PHPMailer's Github example here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) which I placed in my page, and updated the HTML.

Although the image uploads fine and the email comes through, the file attachment is a `.dat` file instead of the correct extension.

Here's my PHP in case something I've changed isn't as it should be:

```
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {

$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->setFrom('my@email.com', 'Competitions');
    $mail->addAddress('jg@email.com', 'JG');
    $mail->Subject = 'Competition Entry';
    $mail->msgHTML("My message body");

    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'Competiton Entry Attachment');
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $err[] = "Mailer Error - didn't send email" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $done[] = "Message sent!";
    }

} else {
    $err[] = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
}

}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You don't give the filename an extension: `'Competiton Entry Attachment'` has none. Try: `'Competiton_Entry_Attachment.doc'` or any other extension. If that doesn't work, give it a type. See the documentation.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - thanks, that works, but i hoped I could upload any type of file for this.... not limited to one i.e. `.doc` as you suggested

Comment: That is another question which I was hoping you could solve yourself... but no need, Shijin T R shows you how.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'Competiton Entry Attachment');
```

To

```
$name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$ext = end((explode(".", $name)));

$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'Competiton Entry Attachment.'.$ext);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. When I tried that, though, it returned `Competition Entry Attachment._tmp_php54Qilm`???? Thanks

Comment: For the record, [here are the docs for `addAttachment`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment).

Comment: I got a simpler solution:

instead of:

`$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'Competiton Entry Attachment');`

just write:

`$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'Competiton_Entry_Attachment.jpg');`

Of course this one only works if all the files are JPG, if other files sent are PNG, TIFF, etc. they won't be received as theri original extension